# referencing canvas using prototypal javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a JavaScript library using prototypes.
The only problem is that I can make my function return getContext, but I don't know how to reference the parent function within a prototype. 'this' doesn't seem to work, so i tried to create a global variable to hold this, but that didn't do much. So I think there's another problem and I'm not sure where to start.

```
 function isometric(id) {
var about = { // Returned if no parameters
    version: 1.0,
    author: "Josh Lalonde"
};


if (id) {
    if (window === this) {
        return new _(id);
    } // Window passed to function.

    this.canvas = document.getElementById(id); // The canvas to draw on.
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   return ctx; //
}
else {
    return about; // Nothing passed.
}


 }
```

Here's the prototype.

```
 isometric.prototype = {
clear: function() { //Clean up
            var ctx = this;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, isometric.width, isometric.height); // Draw a black canvas

   }    


  };
```

My references to the code for testing are such:

```
 var iso = new isometric('canvas');
 iso.clear();
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joshlalonde/r8e2U/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the prototype for isometric but the constructor returns an instance of CanvasRenderingContext2D. The method .clear() is thus not defined. What you could do is to save the context as a property of isometric and then access it from the methods defined in isometric.prototype. To be able to access the methods, you will have to return `this` in the **constructor**:

```
...
this.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
return this;
```

**prototype:**

```
clear:function() { //clean up
    var ctx = this.ctx;
    //Also change the following line (you were using isometric.width, which is not defined)
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height); // Draw a black canvas
```

With these changes your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/UtRLb/1/

Comment: Yep, exactly what I needed. I'll keep this in mind for the other prototypes. Thank you!